# SSRS 2008R2 - KeepTogether causing error on export to PDF

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, export, pdf-generation

I'm running SQL 2008 R2 x64 with SSRS (10.50.4297.0 / SP2 CU10)

I'm having an issue when exporting a report to PDF via it's `reportserver?...&rs:Command=Render` URL despite the report being exported fine in the web Report Viewer (`Reports/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?`)

All reports export successfully (regardless of parameter) using the web Report Viewer but exports through reportserver fail (HTTP 500) on some parameters. The error in the SSRS log is nonsensical.

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSException: The Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix5’ contains an error: The expression that references the field 'MyField19' does not exist in the Fields collection. Expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: The Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix5’ contains an error: The expression that references the field 'MyField19' does not exist in the Fields collection. Expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.
```

The column field definitely exists in the dataset and is referred to correctly in the report (I even examined the XML of the report). If this was truly a problem then why does the report render in the web report viewer and export as PDF there when given the same parameters? Removing the field simply pushes the error onto another field into the dataset.

Dataset takes a while to generate (10-60 seconds) and SQL query is large. No calculated fields in the SSRS dataset and report has no custom controls or VB code.

I don't know where to troubleshoot from here.

Comment: I'm starting to believe it could be some issue triggering on hard page break renderers (such as PDF) as it only seems to occur on reports that have page breaks.

Comment: I think there is still a bug in the KeepTogether property. I'm using it on a large (~10 row) detail row group. When I turn it off and rely on page breaks before/after the group, the report renders fine again except this workaround does not meet my requirements.